# Mounting html files between 2 containers in Docker using sshfs

Tags: docker

i am new to Docker.

I have created two docker images (both Ubuntu 20.04) and a network to use.
In the first image i have installed apache2 web server and on the second one i have installed sshfs.
I want my first image to mount (using sshfs) in the default path :/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
a folder with html files contained in the second image.

Any suggestions on how to start?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked out https://github.com/vieux/docker-volume-sshfs

Comment: Can you say a little bit more about your larger workflow?  In general you want to avoid changing files inside a container if you can; if you're trying to update your published application it might be better to use a custom image `FROM httpd`, `COPY` your HTML and CSS files in, and then `docker build` a new image and `docker run` a new container when the application changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind both of them to same volume on your machine. Use `--volumes-from` to bind them to same path.

Worth a read [Docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/)